# How to calculate UMTS bitrates?

Tags: digital-modes

Assuming:

**Radio frame**

1. Subdivided in 15 slots
2. Number of chips: 38.400
3. Duration: 10 ms; each slots = 666.6 μs and has 2.560 chips

**Example of channels**

**DPDCH (Dedicated Physical Data Channel) (UL)**

- Spreading factor varies between 4 and 256
- Data rates 960, 480, 240, 120, 60, 30 and 15 kbit/s
- Spreading factor 4, 640 bits/slot, 15 slots/frame, 100 frames/s -> 960 kbit/s
- Spreading factor 256, 640 bits/slot, 15 slots/frame, 100 frames/s ->15 kbit/s
- A connection can have at most 6 DPDCH -> 5, 74 Mbit/s

**Question**

I don't really understand how the bitrate for DPDCH is determined like "960kbit/s" for example. Which formula is used to derive these values?

Here is a picture of the frame structure.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Spreading factor 4, 640 bits/slot, 15 slots/frame, 100 frames/s = 960 kbit/s
>
> I don't really understand how the bandwidth for DPDCH is determined like "960kbit/s" for example.

There's no equation. It's just another way of stating the information that's already there. By [dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis):

$$ \require{cancel}
\frac{640\, \text{b}}{\cancel{\text{slot}}}
\frac{15 \cancel{\text{ slot}}}{\cancel{\text{frame}}}
\frac{100 \cancel{\text{frame}}}{s}
\frac{1\,\text{k}}{1000}
= \frac{960\,\text{kb}}{\text{s}}
$$

I also would not call "960 kbit/s" a *bandwidth*. That may be acceptable in the context of say, a PCI bus, but in the context of a radio protocol, *bandwidth* also means the width of the signal in the frequency domain. I'd call it a *bitrate* to avoid that confusion.

Comment: Thank you @Phil you answered my question. Also your emphasis on my usage of "bandwidth" is correct ! Should've been bitrate.